# How can we get the screen size while multitasking?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I want to get the screen size of the view while user split the screen in iPad pro so that I can set the view dynamically as per the requirement?

[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds is giving me whole screen data

Comment: I think you're supposed to handle this with autolayout and size classes in iOS.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, actually my app has dynamic view, so I am not using autolayout

Comment: I need just screen size at that time

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the screen size. Don't use global variables in general.

If you're doing things programatically — and a lot of us see no incompatibility between that and autolayout, just as an aside — use your view's `frame` to determine how large the contents of your view should be.

Answer (score 1):

Try `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].bounds`

Note that you might get odd results when the app is entering/returning from background state, or if you do custom work with the windows.

***Full story:***
I had to implement something similar, my own custom size classes, to determine if my multitasking-supported universal app was in either a compact, regular, or full state (full state defined as being landscape iPad non-split screen) - solved it kinda like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger, OBDTraitStyle) {
    OBDTraitStyleCompact,
    OBDTraitStyleMedium,
    OBDTraitStyleFull
};

static NSNumber *_previousGlobalTraitStyleNumber = nil;

@implementation UITraitCollection (OBD)

- (OBDTraitStyle)obd_traitStyle
{
    UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground)
    {
        if (_previousGlobalTraitStyleNumber != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"App in background - returning previous trait style: %ld", (long)[_previousGlobalTraitStyleNumber integerValue]);
            return [_previousGlobalTraitStyleNumber integerValue];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"App in background - cannot return previous trait style, as it doesn't exist");
        }
    }

    OBDTraitStyle traitStyle = 0;

    if (self.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact)
    {
        traitStyle = OBDTraitStyleCompact;
    }
    else
    {
        UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

        if (window.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact)
        {
            traitStyle = OBDTraitStyleCompact;
        }
        else
        {
            CGSize viewSize = window.bounds.size;
            BOOL horizontalExpanded = (viewSize.width > 768);

            if (horizontalExpanded == NO)
            {
                traitStyle = OBDTraitStyleMedium;
            }
            else
            {
                traitStyle = OBDTraitStyleFull;
            }
        }
    }

    _previousGlobalTraitStyleNumber = @(traitStyle);
    return traitStyle;
}

@end
```